# AddChild() not accessible in RibbonQuickAccessToolBar

Tags: c#, wpf

In the code below, the line 'QuickToolBar.AddChild(SaveBtn)' gives the following error:

> System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.AddChild(object) is inaccessible
>   due to its protection level.

I don't understand the reason for this error message. Please help

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;

namespace Ribbon3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateRibbon();
        }

        public void CreateRibbon()
        {
            Ribbon ribbon = new Ribbon();
            ribbon.SelectedIndex = 0;
            RibbonQuickAccessToolBar QuickToolBar = new RibbonQuickAccessToolBar();
            RibbonButton SaveBtn = new RibbonButton();
            QuickToolBar.AddChild(SaveBtn);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The method is protected:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.addchild(v=vs.110).aspx

A protected member of a base class is accessible in a derived class only if the access occurs through the derived class type.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx

Answer (score 3):

As said by Derek you cannot use `QuickToolBar.AddChild(SaveBtn)` due to protection level. But you still can add using Items.Add like this

```
QuickToolBar.Items.Add(SaveBtn);
```